# Threading custom url query parameters to PowerForm callbacks

Tags: docusignapi

I'm wondering if it is possible to thread custom query parameters through to PowerForm callback urls. For example, given the base PowerForm url of:

`https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=[myFormId]&env=demo&v=2`

I'd like to add the query param `customId=12345` to it:

`https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=[myFormId]&env=demo&v=2&customId=12345`

I'd then like to be able to get that `customId` in the brand callback links. It could either be part of the URL or as part of the body.

Is this possible in any way? Note: I do not want to add a custom field to the form since I am not the one generating the forms, though if that can be done via API it may be acceptable.

Comment: is customId always hardcoded value of 12345 for all signers? and if it is  hardcoded, do you want the value back once signing is completed? and are you comfortable in adding envelope custom fields via API to sent envelopes?

Comment: @AmitKBist the value of `customId` will change for each signer, and yes, we need the value back once signing is complete, ideally just in the query params the same way data currently is passed back to the callback urls. I'm certainly open to an API solution, though right now we don't have API access for our clients who are the ones who manage the PowerForms; they just give us their existing link, and we give them a link to put as the callback urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below soln using API and PF:

With API (using Remote Signing):

- Create Envelope Custom Field in envelope Creation call
- Updated Destination URLs in Branding as explained
  [here](https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/advanced-branding-configuration.htm)
  with the return/callback URL like
  https://www.google.com?customId=[[TestPolicyNumber]], where
  www.google.com is your callback App URL and TestPolicyNumber is the
  Envelope Custom Field added in the envelope Creation call

With PowerForm:

- Create a PF URL
- Create In-Session landing page in DS Account as explained as
  explained in [Configure In-Session landing
  pages](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-specify-a-URL-to-redirect-to-when-a-Powerform-is-completed)
  with similar type of URL as explained with API flow, configure
  return/callback URL like
  https://www.google.com?customId=[[TestPolicyNumber]], where
  www.google.com is your callback App URL and TestPolicyNumber is the
  Envelope Custom Field added in the envelope Creation call
- Append your Query Parameter to PF URL like below

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=d4b09cfb-8264-4fe7-a35d-554294f99445&EnvelopeField_TestPolicyNumber=1234567

where https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=d4b09cfb-8264-4fe7-a35d-554294f99445 is your PF URL
and TestPolicyNumber is the envelope Custom Field and its value is diff for each customer, in above instance it is 1234567.

Now when Customer finishes signing then DocuSign will replace TestPolicyNumber value in call back URL configured in In-Session landing page with the actual value of 1234567 sent as EnvelopeCustomField value when starting the PF flow.
https://www.google.com?customId=[[TestPolicyNumber]]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So, if I understand correctly: for each signer, use the API to make a new envelope, and then create a PF within that envelope? I think what I'm confused about is that that In-Session landing pages only work for the first signer of the PF, so I'd have to make a new PF for each signer. Is that correct?

Comment: NO, both solutions are different based on the approach you want to select, if you want to do everything with API then use only API approach. But if you want to use only Powerform then use only PF approach. In-Session landing pages are used for first Signer on the Direct PF (Direct PF is PF without email validation). If you have multiple signers in your Template/PF then you need to update both In-Session Landing page for first signer and update Branding's Destination URL for subscequent signers.

Comment: So, using the PF option with no API call, what do you mean by "the
Envelope Custom Field added in the envelope Creation call"?

Comment: If you are pursuing PF flow, then you can create Envelope Custom Field in an envelope by adding query parameter like `EnvelopeField_TestPolicyNumber=1234567` appended to the PF URL, where TestPolicyNumber is an Envelope Custom Field, and the value of this Envelope Custom Field will be used in the callback URL configured in InSession Landing page.

Comment: Hmm. Using the `EnvelopeField_*` method seems to cause the PF to no longer open. The loading bar for the page goes to full, but the form is never shown. Do Envelop Custom Fields need to be configured before going to the link?

Comment: Remove two query parameters from the URL- `&env=demo&v=2`, currently DocuSign is doing fix for this issue, but if you remove these two query parameters then it will load the signing page without any issue.